Connecting two dipole antennas for local TV
Sequel to a previous question …
I put a balun on the end of one of the antenna lines and ran RG6/U into a TV.  Some local channels were fine; some not there.  Since the two antennas are dipoles and pointing different directions, I assume the only problem is that they are directional.  Each antenna originally went to a different room in the house; seems weird to change rooms according to what you want to watch.  Now the different stations are of course on different frequencies, so I think putting them in parallel will not present an interference problem.  Is there any problem with running a 300Ω flat cable from one antenna to the other?  Or should I abandon both and buy one of those new-fangled flat plate antennas?

If the problem is that the stations you want to watch are in different directions, buying a flat plate antenna may make things worse.  It all depends on the beam width/pattern of the antenna, and how far apart, in angular degrees, the stations are.

Well, these flat antennas claim to be multidirectional.  One reviewer got 68 stations with one called "Mohu Leaf."

Can you run two coax cables from the attic to the TV set? Then use a switch to select the antenna you want.

@ThePhoton, No, the flat lines go inside the walls to plug-ins in the walls of two of the rooms.  Each antenna feeds a different room. The only way easy enough for me is to put a balun in one or both plug-in boxes, and run the coax under the house to a new wall box near the TV.  The guy who built the house is deceased, so I can't ask him why he put his TV connections in places where it is not possible to have furniture facing them!  Or why he watched soe channels in this room and others in that room!

@SteveSh, we have sixteen stations transmitting from three locations.  The two closest farms are about thirty degrees apart in the southwest, and the further one is northwest.  If I remember right, the two antennas are aimed Southwest.

A simple directional antenna will probable work,  In fact, with the beam width being relative broad for a simple dipole, you could try a single dipole oriented half way between the two main clusters of stations.

And like others have said, you just can't connect multiple antennas, or antenna elements together and expect any improvement.  In any cases you could make things worse.  The physics just doesn't work out that way.

When you say "aim the dipole", keep in mind that the best reception comes when the dipole is broadside to the signal.

That's unclear.  Isn't it when the split bars are perpendicular to the direction to the transmitter?  Not that it matters for an antenna that cannot be rotated.  And, even if image quality is degraded, getting ten stations instead of four does not "make things worse."

Paralleling the antennas will reduce the signal level of each.
The typical way to handle stations in different directions is to use an antenna rotator.

I know that. But these are installed inside an attic and can't be rotated.  I may have to resort to an amplifier in the crawl space.  Or pay Comcast $26 a month for local channels :-(

NOOOO!  Anything but Comcast!
